# NFC Enabled SIM APDU Response 6A 82

Tags: nfc, apdu

I am working on NFC enabled SIM, using ISO-7816-4. While I try to SELECT MF, DF or EF, response is always 6A 82( File not found). Following are the APDUs

`00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00` -> To SELECT MF

`00 A4 00 00 02 2F E2` -> To SELECT EF

`00 A4 00 00 02 7F 20` -> To SELECT DF

Response is always the same, i.e., 6A 82. Am I missing something here? Kindly help.

Comment: What happens when you just send `00 A4 00 00` to let the card choose what to return?

Comment: When I send `00 A4 00 00`, it responds with 6A 86 (Incorrect P1-P2 Parameter). Interesting thing is when I send GET CHALLENGE command, it responds it correctly. I am trying to communicate with it using  ACR122U213 NFC Reader/Writer.

Comment: the reader is not important because it sends commands to the card using the ISO7816 and ISO 14443 standards. This means the reader is just a means, not really all that important. As for new error.. Did you send the RATS command before trying to read the card?

Comment: No I didn't. Can you please share the APDU for RATS? Vendor says Mifare sector is embedded on this SIM, according to the specifications it looks like 1k.

Comment: The ATR of this NFC is not listed anywhere. UID is of 4 Bytes.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? If No, Please share the ATR of the Card. And also the response to the `00 A4 04 00`

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Amir The story is bit long. SAK value of the NFC enabled SIM was set to 0x28, which means it supports both CPU APDUs and ISO 14443-3 (Mifare 1k). This was the reason reader was unable to communicate with Mifare 1k sector that was in the SIM. Once SAK value set to 0x08, my reader started communicating with Mifare 1k sector.

Comment: So,The problem solved?

Comment: Yes. Now its working great.

Comment: So please add an answer here,explain how did you solved your problem and checked it as correct solution for other people :)

Maybe we can share our experience to each other. This is my email address: ebr.ghasemi@gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with **APDUs**, but with the value of `SAK`. `SAK` value was set to **0x28**. 
Which means NFC enabled SIM supports both;

1. CPU level APDUs (the one I was trying to communicate to) and
2. Mifare 1k sector (the one I should have tried to communicate to in the first place).

However CPU level APDUs had more priority than Mifare sector because of which my NFC reader/writer was unable to communicate to Mifare 1k sector. Once the value of `SAK` was changed to **0x08**, it disabled CPU level APDUs and my NFC reader/writer was able to communicate with the Mifare 1k sector. Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please explain how to set SAK value and how to check that.. i am struggling from last 48 hours with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548209/69-82security-condition-not-satisfied-adpu-resposne-with-android-nfc

Comment: It is set by manufacturing company and is hardcoded as far as I know.

Comment: SAK value is 0x28 for me as well. That means i wont be able to read any binary from the NFC smart card. ??? But this works for me with my java application using javax.smartcardio.

Answer (score 0):

Your P2 is incorrect. However, I'm not sure why the card is returning status `6A 82` (File not found) instead of `6A 86` (Incorrect parameters to P1 to P2).

To select by FID (File Identifier), you need to set the P2 as follow:

1. `P2=04`. In case of successful SELECT, you will get status `61XX`. Send GET RESPONSE and you will have the FCP Template in the response data.
2. `P2=0C`. In case of successful SELECT, no data returned. Only status `9000`.

For more details of P1 and P2, refer to ETSI 102.221 section 11.1.1. You can download the file [from this ETSI link](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102221/11.01.00_60/ts_102221v110100p.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, here I would like to add that I talked with the manufacturer of this SIM card. He told me that I am trying to communicate with the CPU of the SIM, instead he told me that there is a Mifare sector on this SIM (1k classic). But when I send APDU of ISO-14443, reader sends back nothing. So again I contacted manufacturer, now he told me that SAK of the SIM is set to 0x28, which means it supports both CPU and Mifare and my reader is currently ignoring Mifare sector because CPU priority is high. So in this case if SAK is changed to 0x08, it will work fine.

Comment: Is there a way to change value of SAK myself?